# Set of matrices as a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the set $\{A \in M_{2*2}(\mathbb{R}) \:|\: AB = 0\}$ a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

where $B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &-2  \\
-3 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$

--

Since any matrix A of the form

$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1  \\
3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ times a constant $c$

will satisfy the condition is it enough to show closure under addition and multiplication without checking all the vector space axioms, if so why?

thanks

Comment: Are matrices of this form the only matrices which satisfy the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if $V$ is a vector space and $W$ a subset of $V$ which is closed under addition and scalar multiplication and contains 0, then $W$ is a vector space under the restrictions of the operations on $V$. $W$ is then called a subspace of $V$.

The various vector space axioms are not hard to show: $W$ has additive inverses since $(-1).v=-v$, and addition is commutative and associative because these properties follow from those for $V$, so $W$ is an abelian group. That scalar multiplication on $W$ also obeys the relevant axioms again follows from those axioms for $V$.

With regards to your first question, whether $\{A \in M_{2*2}(\mathbb{R}) \:|\: AB = 0\}$ is a vector space, as you suspected it can be shown to be a vector space by showing that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Have you tried to show this?

Comment: yes I have, it follows from the distributive property of matrix multiplication and the commutative property of scalar multiplication. thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that $A_1 B = 0, A_2 B = 0$ implies that $(A_1 + A_2)B = 0$ and $(cA_1) B = 0$. Which shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. that is part of my question, why is it enough to check closure under addition and multiplication, rather than all the vector space axioms?

Comment: This is a simple theorem, we just restrict the operations, so all axioms stay true, we just need to check that the set is closed under the operations of the large matrix vector space.